# Cannot use matplotlib library?

Tags: matplotlib, pip, pycharm, python-3.6

I am getting a weird error when calling any function with matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib as plt
plt.bar(np.arange(7, [1,3,2,1,4,6,1])
```

I get this error:

```
IPython.core.display.Javascript object

IPython.core.display.HTML object

Traceback (most recent call last): self.kernel.session.send(self.kernel.iopub_socket, msg_type,*

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'**
```

I have already tried:

1. upgrade my pip
2. upgrade matplotlib
3. installing pyplot (which brings error --> Non-zero exit code (1) --> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyplot)

My Matplotlib version = 3.3.3
OS --> Windows 10

Nothing seems to work and I am stuck. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: matplotlib contains pyplot, so there's no need to update both. which backend are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing wrongly the library.

Usually one use

```
import matplotlib as mpl
```

(seldom used) or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

You are mixing the two imports/names, and so also the interface. Use the second import I wrote, for `plt` (pyplot).

Ho to debug? When you gain experience, you will learn that usually the problems are in your code and not on environment. So stop upgrading/reinstalling (often you worse the situation, see this site for examples). So try to debug your code. Check the matplotlib page of bar plots. Copy example, modify little things until you have your expected code. (Usually with such steps you find the error).